# C++ Prevent copy a member data

Tags: c++

I have a unusual situation,

Say I have a class like the following,

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
    public :

    C (int size) : value_(size), some_other_member_(size) {}

    T &value () {return value_;}
    const T &value() const {return value_;}

    private :

    T value_;
    SomeOtherType some_other_member_;
 };
```

The class designed such that the client can have full access to the member `value_`, just like `std::vector`'s `operator[]` will return a reference, this class also *have to* give client the full access through returning a reference. A setter/getter pair will not do.

However, unlike `std::vector`, I don't want to allow the client to be able to replace the member entirely. That is, the client shall be able to call `const` or non-`const` members of `value_`, but the following shall not be allowed,

```
 C<SomeType> c(10);
 SomeType another_value(5);
 c.value() = another_value; // This shall not be allowed
```

Is there any possible way that I can give client the full access to `value_`. In some sense, the class `C` shall be like a container, but once the thing it contained is initialized (through the constructor, there are requirements to `T`, but that is not relevant here), client can only modify `value_` through `T`'s member functions, not replace `value_` by assignment.

However, requires `T` be un-copyable is not an option to me. Because the class `C` can be copied. At the core of the problem, is that as seen in the class `C`, `C` has a few members, they all have a `size` property, when constructed, they are all constructed with the same `size`, if `value_` is allowed to be replaced through assignment, then it allows the data structure being corrupt in the sense that members may no longer have the same `size` property.

Requiring `T` to only allow copy or assignment when the size is the same is also not an option. Because, when copy a `C` object, the size can be different between the source and the destination. For example,

```
C c1(10);
C c2(20);
c1 = c2;
```

is perfectly reasonable. The size of `c1` is changed, but all of its members are also changed to the same new size, so it is OK.

I hope I have stated the problem clear. I summary, I want `C` does not pose much restriction on `T`, `T` can be basically any type with a required constructor. `T` can be copied and assigned. The only thin I don't want client to do is assignment to `value_` through `C::value()`.

Comment: If you provide an non-const reference to the value, it can be modified. So don't provide that. A const reference is enough to just read the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to call non-const member functions on the object and you want to return a reference to the actualy object, you can't completely prohibit assignment, since the assignment operator is basically just that (you can rewrite `a = b` as `a.operator=(b)`). Therefore you either need to return only a const reference to your object, make the contained object `non_copyable` or live with the fact, that it can be assigned to.

Personally I would suggesting rethinking the design. Even if you could disallow assignment, there are really no guarantees that the object doesn't have a member function, which does basically the same think (`.swap(...)` is a typical candidate), so you haven't really won anything as long as you allow calling non const memberfunctions.

However if you are only concerned with disallowing accidential assignments, you can make it harder to make such an assignment. If your `T` isn't a builtin, you could create a derived class, which doesn't expose a public assignment operator and return a reference to that:

```
template <typename T>
class C{
public :
    class Derived: public T {
    private:
       Derived(int size):T(size) {}
       Derived& operator=(const Derived&) = default; //used C++11 syntax for brevity, for C++03 code it has to be implemented here
       Derived(const Derived&) = default; //don't want this class to be copyied outside of C
       ~Derived() = default;
       friend class C;    
    };

    C (int size) : value_(size), some_other_member_(size) {}
    Derived& value () {return value_;}
    const Derived& value() const {return value_;}
 private :
    Derived value_;
    SomeOtherType some_other_member_;
 };
```

This will give access to all public members by inheritence, but hide assignment operator (and constructors). Of course if you use c++11, this code could be enhanced by using/defining move constructors/assignments and using perfect forwarding, to allow different constructors. Note that the T-part of Derived can still be assigned to using `static_cast<T&>(C.value()) = foo`;

To support types you can't derive from (builtins...), you'd need to create a proxy, which exposes all functionality except assignments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very brilliant. Though there are still some details I may need to think about, but it is a good strategy I can use (the inner class idea is really neat). The point is to prevent accidental assignment. If user want to use some member functions explicitly change the internal if value, the can do it on their own. I some sense, it is their object, and they can do whatever they want as long as they know what they are doing

Answer (score 1):

As to your getter/setter problem, I would write

```
const T& value() const; // as getter
void value(const T&); // as setter
```

Returning `const T&` (const-reference) is exactly against situations like `c.value() = 10` (see eg. Effective C++ by Scott Meyers, item 23).

I think this also solves the copy problem: your class remains copyable.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that this is not an option. Because users will not be able to call non const members of value without making a copy, then copy back. That is simply not efficient and sometimes impossible. It is more like a container which returns non const reference